# foreach checkbox POST in php

Tags: php, post, checkbox

Basically my question is the following, how can i select on "Checked" checkbox's while doing a $_POST request in PHP, currently i have the checkbox's doing an array as shown below.

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="2" name="checkbox[]">
<input type="checkbox" value="3" name="checkbox[]">
```

I want to be able to do something like this

```
foreach(CHECKED CHECKBOX as CHECKBOX) {
   echo CHECKBOX VALUE;
}
```

I've tried doing similar to that and it's not echoing anything.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
foreach($_POST['checkbox'] as $value) {

}
```

Note that `$_POST['checkbox']` will *only* exist if at least one checkbox is checked. So you **must** add an `isset($_POST['checkbox'])` check before that loop. The easiest way would be like this:

```
$checkboxes = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : array();
foreach($checkboxes as $value) {
    // here you can use $value
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for providing such an explanation and it worked perfect.

Comment: How do you store the values of checkboxes in an array?

Answer (score 0):

This type of questions can be easily understood printing `$_POST`: `var_dump($_POST);`. You'll see that PHP receive values of checked checkboxes in numeric array.

```
foreach ( $_POST['checkbox'] as $value ) {
    echo $value;
}
```