# How can I get info from these buttons on the server side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have [these buttons](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio) inside a form. How can I know which ones were selected when the user submits the form?

```
<form action="/">
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
      </label>
    </div>
<input type="submit value="submit"></input>

</form>
```

Comment: i dont see a form... please post your whole html script

Comment: possible duplicate of [foreach checkbox POST in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543050/foreach-checkbox-post-in-php)

Comment: @Deer-Outdoor.nl This post is not tagged with php - is he using php on the server side? He hasn't said so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your button group is a bootstrap style group and means nothing on the server side.

Your inputs will need to be named in order to produce a value from the form's postback.

```
<form action="/">
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input name="check1" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked> Checkbox 1 (pre-checked)
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="check2" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input name="check3" type="checkbox" autocomplete="off"> Checkbox 3
  </label>
</div>
```