# Trying to email check boxs in php form

Tags: php, html, forms, foreach

I have several checkboxes in a form. And I'm trying to echo those values into an email. 
Here is the HTML:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox2">App Design</label>
                        <input id="checkbox2" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox1">Design</label>
                        <input id="checkbox3" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox2">Email Design</label>
                        <input id="checkbox4" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox1">Layout Design</label>
                        <input id="checkbox5" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox1">Poster Design</label>
                        <input id="checkbox6" type="checkbox" name="work-check[]"><label for="checkbox2">Web Design</label>
```

And here is the PHP:

```
    <?php

    if ($_POST["submit"]) {


        if(!filter_var($_POST[email], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

            echo '<div data-alert class="alert-box warning">E-mail is not valid</div>';
            $error=true;
        }

        if($error==false) {

            $result='<div data-alert class="alert-box success">Form Submitted</div>';

            $headers = array("From: myemail@mail.com",
            "Reply-To: myemail@mail.com",
            "X-Mailer: PHP/" . PHP_VERSION
            );
            $headers = implode("\r\n", $headers);

            // the message
            // the message
        $msg = "
        First Name: ".$_POST['first_name']." 

        Last Name: ".$_POST['last_name']."

        Email: ".$_POST['email']."

        Options: ".implode(",", $_POST['work-check']);


            // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
            $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

            $to = "myemail@mail.com";

            $subject = "New Request";

            mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
        }
    }

    echo $result;
?>
```

I think I have it set up that I should get an array back called work-check. I just don't know php well enough to know how to cycle through that array and set the values I get back.
I found something like this which I think might be going in the right direction:

```
        // The array will only contain the checked value of forms
        foreach($golfer as $g) {
       // can use checkbox value here

}
```

I'm not sure where in the php code that should go.

Comment: few things, ID's are unique and you have one that's repeating for your checkboxes. Then this is never closed `$msg = "` and this needs quoting `$_POST[email]` - just at a quick glance of course

Comment: Each ID is different, shouldn't that work? The email works, I get back the first / last name and email, just not the options.

Comment: (1) None of your `<input type="checkbox" name="work-check[]">` have a value, so it will only post the default `1` if they are checked. (2) since `$_POST['work-check']` is an array -> `name="work-check[]"` you need to do something like `Options: ".implode(', ' , $_POST['work-check']);`

Comment: You're almost there... this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543050/foreach-checkbox-post-in-php will help you. Google "foreach checkbox post php" to further your research ;-) Edit: `$_POST[email]` should *probably* read as `$_POST['email']`.

Comment: again `$msg = "` you never closed this. If what you posted is your actual code, not closing it, will throw a parse error, but your system probably isn't setup to catch and display errors/notices etc. You're also open to XSS injection with the way you have your POST arrays in like that.

Comment: @Fred-ii- it looks like `$msg = "` is a multiline declaration, with it ending/closing on line `Options: ".$_POST['work-check'];`

Comment: @Sean You may be right ;-) *I stand corrected*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You are spot on all your other observations though

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store it as a string

```
    //Store the array from the post as an array
    $arr = $_POST['work-check'];
    //implode the array into a string variable
    $options = implode( ",", $arr );
```

Or, keep it as an array and iterate over it doing what you want.

```
    $arr = $_POST['work-check'];
    foreach ($arr as &$value) {
        ...
    }

    unset($value); // break the reference with the last element
```

See the PHP manual for some more usage examples of [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) and [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

Comment: how would I set the value for each time it looped into a post for the email collection? $msg = "
            First Name: ".$_POST['first_name']." 

            Last Name: ".$_POST['last_name']."

            Email: ".$_POST['email']."

            Options: ".$_POST['work-check'];

            $arr = $_POST['work-check'];
      foreach ($arr as &$value) {
          ...
      }

      unset($value); // break the reference with the last element

Comment: well that didn't really work....

Comment: so I've updated my message part based off of the information you provided, and it worked, but I'm not getting back any values just a yes string. Is that correct?

Comment: Got it.. I was missing the values....thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Give the checkboxes a value
This should give you an idea:

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
  $work = implode( '<br>', $_POST['work'] );
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?= $work ?>

<form method="post">
  <input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="Design"> Design<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="work[]" value="Email Design"> Email Design<br>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<?= $work ?>` that will throw an undefined variable work notice on page load; be careful with that. Best to use a ternary operator.

Comment: This was an example of checkbox and values, everyone should handle notices and warnings.

Comment: that's a poor excuse. You're showing bad coding practice. Of all people, you should know better. Sorry Tom, but I don't agree with your comment.

Comment: This is exactly why i rarely contribute to stackowerflow, generally too much trolling. I always declare variables in my work, but in this topic it wasnt the issue and i dont write plug-in solutions. You can think, feel and write however you like about it, in this answer it isnt relevant for the problem in hand.

Comment: "Trolling"........... *facepalm* - whatever. Let me gas up my boat; a real "troller". Want some crab when I get back from the high seas?